# Is there a way to make a permission request for opening app from another app appear again after allowing it once? (iOS)

Tags: ios

So we have a task that app1 needs to copy some data to clibboard then open app2 which reads this data from clipboad and uses it. This is already implemented and works. But the first time app1 need to access app2 iOS wanted me confirm that action with the following dialog: "app1 wants to open app2" with options to Open or Cancel. I pressed Open and now it never shows this dialog. However we need this dialog because we want to thorougly test this process, including the case when user presses Cancel. Is there any way to bring this dialog back without wiping our iphones?

We have tried:

- Reinstalling both app1 and app2
- Restarting device
- Enabling and disabling developer mode (ios 16)
- Enabling and disabling lockdown mode (ios 16)
- Changing system time forward

None of these actions made this dialog to appear again. Wiping and reactivating and iphone will work of course but maybe there is a faster way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Open the iPhone Settings app
2. Select "General"
3. Select "Transfer or Reset iPhone"
4. Select "Reset"
5. Select "Reset Location & Privacy"
6. If that doesn't work, select "Reset All Settings"

Comment: That seems unnecessarily extreme.

Comment: @Caleb, it works though and it's much better than erasing device and activating it again so it will do.

Arik Segal, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting "app1" before re-installing it. When you just install a new app over the old one, the data associated with the old one remains in place. Deleting the app first should remove it and hopefully remove the permission to launch "app2" in the process.

Comment: By "reinstalling" I meant deleting and installing app from scratch. So I have tried it already